# getresponse() returns tuple back as string

Tags: python, flask, https, tuples

Hello Im trying to get several variables and a list from an aws lambda function but I can only return one value(either the variable or the list). I tried returning them both as a tuple but when I tried extracting the tuple it was a string. I am planning on using the objects in the tuple and need them to be extracted as the same type that they were taken as. how do I return them both as their original types

This is what the tuple looks like in my aws lambda function

```
tup = (value1,[1,2,3])
```

and from my flask app that reads the response of the lambda function

```
response = c.getresponse()
data = response.read().decode('utf-8')[0]
```

But when I try to index my tuple, and do data[0] it prints out the first bracket which I am assuming that its been read as a string

Comment: on network all is send as string/text or bytes. You should rather convert all data to JSON and return it - and in flask you should convert JSON back to data. You can't send object. You would try to use `pickle` to convert object to bytes and send it - and flask may try to convert it back if it has definition of class  used to create objet. So JSON seems simpler, safer for sending data - and many (www) servers use JSON . For example `Flask` has `jsonify()` to send information as JSOn.

Answer (score 0):

you can send your response like this in JSON format.

```
data = { "value1": value1, "list": [1,2,3] }
return data
```

Create a dictionary of all the values which you want to send as a response and return it.